# Solve for time, given distance and acceleration

Tags: physics

Two gangsters are flying down I-70 West at a constant 108 hm/hr. If they make it to Indiana, they will be safe. When they are 1 km away from the Indiana border, while still traveling at a constant 108 km/hr, they pass a concealed police car hidden in a speed trap. At the instant that the criminals pass the patrol car, the cop pulls onto the highway and accelerates at a constant rate of 2 m/s^2. Does the cop catch up with them before they cross the state line?

Here's what I have progressed so far

> ΔV = (ΔX)/(T)
>
> when V is velocity, X is distance, and T is time.
>
> 108 = (1 - 0)/T
>
> 108T = 1
>
> T = 1/108
>
> T = 0.00925 hours
>
> T = 0.00925 * 60 * 60
>
> T = 33.33 seconds (this is the time it takes the gangsters to get to
>   the borders of Indiana)

What I am stuck at is the time it takes the cop to travel the same distance. I have used the distance formula to find time as follows:

> Xf = Xi + 1/2 * A * T^2
>
> where A is acceleration
>
> Since the cop is starting from rest, the initial velocity is 0 (zero),
>   so
>
> 1 = 0 + 1/2 * (2) * T^2
>
> 1 = T^2
>
> T = 1 seconds

So it takes the cop 1 seconds to travel the whole mile to Indiana? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: disregard this comment

Comment: Check your calculation for $60 \times 60 / 108$.  Then correct the distance in the second calculation to m instead of km.  It is advisable to do all your calculations in the same units.

Comment: You should be getting 33.3 seconds to reach the border: at 108 km/hr, it should take on the order of a hundredth of an hour to travel 1 km.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the gangsters' speed to ms$^{-1}$, $108$ km/h $=108/3.6$ ms$^{-1} = 30$ ms$^{-1}$.

The distance the cop travelled in time $t$ s is $\frac12at^2 = t^2$ metres, and the distance the gangsters travelled in time $t$ s is $30t$ metres. The time when they met the second time is
$$\begin{align*}t^2 =& 30t\\t=&30\text{ seconds}\end{align*}$$

Then the distance they have travelled in $30$ seconds is $900$ metres, and this is before they arrive Indiana.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration is in meters/second^2 but the distance is 1 kilometer=1000 meters.  The left side should be 1000, not 1.

Comment: He is saying that your second equation should be 1000 m. $ \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot T^2 \ . $  (Justice prevails, but just barely...)